# Angular 2 + firefox + input + type=date datepicker does not show

Tags: firefox, angular, shim

> Code works correct in Chome browser

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="date">Date:</label>
    <input class="form-control " [(ngModel)]="journal.record.date" type="date" required/>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="timeEntered">Time Entered:</label>
    <input class="form-control " [(ngModel)]="journal.record.entered" type="time" required/>
</div>
```

> But Firefox does not show datepicker and timepicker

HTML contains:

```
<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
<!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
```

or:

```
<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
<!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
```

It does not help

I started to check WebShim [enter link description here](https://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/) it does not work too

How can I improve such issue?

Comment: Firefox doesn't support date and time input types - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it's lots of extra work. Maybe we will get one in [angular](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/675) soon.

index.html

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/webshim/minified/polyfiller.js"></script>
<script>
    webshim.setOptions('basePath', '/js/webshim/minified/shims/');
    // http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/demos/cfgs/input-date.html#min=&max=&value=&list=&placeholder=&startView=2&minView=0&size=1&startValue=&useDecadeBase=0&calculateWidth=on&popover=&popover=&popover=&show-week=on
    webshim.setOptions('forms', {
        lazyCustomMessages: true,
        addValidators: true,
        extendNative: true
    });
    webshim.setOptions('forms-ext', {
        replaceUI: 'auto',
        types: 'date',
        date: {
            startView: 2,
            size: 1,
            classes: 'hide-spinbtns'
        }
    });
    webshim.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
</script>
```

app.module.ts

```
...
import { WebshimPolyfill } from '../webshim-polyfill';

@NgModule({
    imports: [...
    ],
    declarations: [
        WebshimPolyfill,
        ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        // The main app component
        AppComponent
    ]
})
...
```

webshim-polyfill.ts

```
import { Directive, AfterViewInit, Input, EventEmitter, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

declare var webshim: any;
declare var $: any;


@Directive({
    selector: '[webshimPolyfill]',
    outputs: ['ngModelChange']
})

export class WebshimPolyfill implements AfterViewInit {
    private ngModelChange = new EventEmitter();
    @Input() validatevalue: Function;
    @Input() thisarg;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        let id = this.el.nativeElement.id;
        $("#" + id).updatePolyfill();
        if (this.validatevalue)
            $("#" + id).on('validatevalue', 
                (e: any, data: any) => {
                    return this.validatevalue.apply(this.thisarg, [e, data]);
            });

        // this library creates a shadow dom element for <input type="date"
        // do this if we want to work with the visible element
        /* let elShadow = $("#" + id).getShadowElement()[0];
         * elShadow.onchange = (event) => {
         */

        // don't use function(){} as this becomes the element not this 
        // and we cannot then ngModelChange.emit.
        this.el.nativeElement.onchange = (event) => {
            this.ngModelChange.emit(this.el.nativeElement.value);
        };

        // (change) on <input> element doesn't work right now
        // maybe 'export as' can fix that
// https://medium.com/@NetanelBasal/angular-2-take-advantage-of-the-exportas-property-81374ce24d26#.jnpr99ncb 
    }
    // webshim.setOptions is done in index.html as per webshims suggestion.
}
```

form.component.html

```
<input webshimPolyfill [validatevalue]="validDay" [thisarg]="thisarg" type="date" id="someDate" formControlName="someDate" [(ngModel)]="someDate" (change)="onChangeSomeDate();" >
```